# Компонент выбора недели

Tags: php

[image]

Как сделать такую строку со стрелками, где будут даты по неделям с этого массива? И при выборе этой недели выводили эти дни. Стрелки переходили на следующую и предыдущую неделю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, даты лучше использовать в формате `unix-timestamp`. Недели считать очень просто: 7 x 24 x 60 x 60 (7 дней x 24 часа x 60 минут x 60 секунд) = 604 800 секунд. Это Ваша неделя.

Передачу данных и ответ возложите на плечи ajax. Если очень нужно, то могу поделиться своей реализацией.

Comment: kemerov4anin, да нужно, если не сложно поделитесь.

Comment: почту бы вашу